# Textbox with textmode = date does not show data

Tags: c#

I have a text item with textmode = date. I want to show a date from database stored procedure. i am using following code, but it is not working. I have searched a lot in this forum but I couldn't find a solution so I am posting a new question.

```
string conn = "";

            conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ToString();

            SqlConnection objsqlconn = new SqlConnection(conn);
            SqlDataReader objDR;
            try
            {
                objsqlconn.Open();
                SqlCommand objcmd = new SqlCommand("GET_DATA", objsqlconn);
                objcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                objDR = objcmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (objDR.Read())
                {
                    txtName.Text = objDR["NAME"].ToString();
                    txtDOB.Text = objDR["DOB"].ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                objsqlconn.Close();
            }
```

Comment: Did you debug and check `objDR.["DOB"]` what comes in?

Comment: I agree, I think debugging code should solve the problem easily

Comment: dob is date column in database table :/

Comment: How it is not working? Do you get any error? Did you debug the code?

Comment: debug the value showing date 27-aug-2001 12:00:00 AM.

Comment: and textitem is showing null---dd----yyyy

Comment: Probably the issue is with the format of Date

Comment: yes may be but pls tell how to resolve it.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: yes right sorry, im using ASP.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert `objDR["DOB"]`  value to `DateTime` and while set value of the `textbox` convert to the `Tostring()`, It might be throw exception of object Reference.

```
txtDOB.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(objDR["DOB"]).ToString();
```

it works like:

```
txtDOB.Text = Convert.ToDateTime("27-Aug-2001 12:00:00 AM").ToString();
```

Comment: i tried this but this: txtDOB.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(objDR["DOB"]).ToString(); but this also not showing date in txtDOB:(

Comment: @ShahzadAsghar can you please show me actual value of objDR["DOB"] without conversion to any type.

Comment: thanx Avinash. i debug the code and obgDR["DOB"]) value is  27-aug-2001 12:00:00 AM